# How to Deal with Environment Variables on Same Machine in Api Requests

Tags: php, guzzle

I have the following scenario:

I have two Domains: domain1.local and domain2.local . They are both set via hosts file to the ip 127.0.0.1 . The Applications on both domains use environment variables by defining them in a .env file ( Concrete5 and Laravel )

I am trying to make an api request like this:

```
    // executed on domain1.local
    // GuzzleHttpClient
    $client = new Client([
        'query' => ['some_query_data' => '123']
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('domain2.local/api/test');
```

The problem is, that both applications use Environment Variables with same names like DB_DATABASE. So if  I execute the api call to domain2.local the environment variables of domain1.local are used and a database error occures.

Is there a convenient way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in the following way:

1. You have not correctly specified the directories in the
   configuration of your web server
2. You have not correctly configured
   .env files

Comment: Hmm.... If I don't use .env files at all the process works fine. This rules out 1.  And as far as I know .env files can't be 'configured'.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild if no env, everything works okay. Can you show an error that appears when using .env?

Comment: The error is just a 500 Server Error response. But this is caused by using the wrong database. The database specified in domain1.local is used by the api endpoint of domain2.local.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Do you use one base for domain1.local and domain2.local?

Comment: What do you mean with one base? There are two completely different systems. One is Laravel and One is concrete5 but both are installed on the same host system.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I just do not understand this sentence:  **The database specified in domain1.local is used by the api endpoint of domain2.local** what is meant : **is used by the api endpoint of domain2.local**

Comment: It is a bit confusing to explain... If I open the url 'domain2.local/api/test' with the browser no error occures. But if I make a get request from domain1.local to 'domain2.local/api/test'  The logs in domain2.local say that something is wrong with database connection. And I can also see in the logs that the db credentials from application1 are used instead of the ones defined via env variables in domain2.  I assume It has to do that on both applications the variables have the same name.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Look, you can change the name to .env Laravel. For example, there is
`DB_CONNECTION = mysql`
`DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1`
`DB_PORT = 3306`
`DB_DATABASE = homestead`
`DB_USERNAME = homestead`
`DB_PASSWORD = secret`
you can change them as you want, but then do not forget to change the configuration file `config/database.php`

Comment: Yes, of course I could change the names. But isnt it possible to use the same environment variables on two different domains? At first I thought, that Guzzle somehow sends that varibales in the request, but now I think that php environment variables are host specific and not domain specific... ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Yes, these variables should be tied to the domain. I had 2 projects on laravel and everything was okay, there were no problems with .env files and variables had the same name. I just suggested this way to check if it works properly or even at all.